# devise after_sign_up_path_for not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-confirmable

I have followed the directions here:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-(registration)

I am succesfully using my own registrations controller.  Here is my routes code:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: "users/registrations", sessions: "users/sessions", passwords: "users/passwords", confirmations: "users/confirmations"}
```

Here is my controller code:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    def new
        super
    end

    def create
         puts "in my custom create action"
         super
    end

    protected

    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
        puts "in after sign up path for"
        if resource.new_record? #user not created. Do default behavior: render new user page
            puts "new record"
        else #user created
            puts "user created"
            return new_user_session_path
        end
    end
end
```

I know the create action is being called because the `puts "in my custom create action"` appears in the server logs.  For some reason, after_sign_up_path_for(resource) is not being called.  I am using Devise confirmable - will that make a difference.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `confirmable` does make a difference, as the user is not yet active in the system.  You can do this instead in your custom controller:

```
def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for resource
  # Custom code here
end
```